# Using a single Microsoft authentication in frontend with Angular and in backend with Django REST API

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, azure-authentication

I have recently made a working Django app which uses resources from MS Graph, where users authenticate in the same fashion as [this tutorial's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?tutorial-step=3).

I was then required to separate frontend, using Angular, and convert my Django app into a REST framework. I managed to set up frontend authentication in Angular [as taught here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/angular).

My question is: how can I use the token that was acquired in frontend to authenticate app's requests to my Django REST API, in order that the backend can also use it for its own queries to MS Graph API?

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the frontend part, you have to pass `{ withCredentials: true }`

```
this.http.get('http://www.example.com/api/auth', { withCredentials: true }).subscribe((resp: any) => {
  console.log(resp)
}
```

I am not familiar with Django, however, in the backend, the idea is to set `SupportCredential` to `true` and nor providing wildcard `*` to allowed origins. You have to mention the path of your specific frontend url

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you have stored the access-token in the frontend in the time of login, then you can send the access-token in the header of the request. In the backend, just check for the header.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'access-token'
  })
};

this.http.get('http://www.example.com/api/endpoint', httpOptions).subscribe(res => {
},
err => {
});
```

For reference: https://angular.io/guide/http